# Failed to call delegatecall()

Tags: ethers.js, proxy-contracts

I'm trying to set up a simple Proxy contract with `delegatecall` but it keeps failing, and I don't know where the problem might be.

`Proxy.sol`

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract Proxy {
    uint num;
    address sender;
    uint value;

    function setVars(address _contract, uint _num) public payable returns(uint, string memory) {
        (bool success, ) = _contract.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setVars(uint)", _num)
        );
        require(success, "Delegate call failed");
        return (0, "");
    }
}
```

`Logic.sol`

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract Logic {
    uint num;
    address sender;
    uint value;

    event ProxyEvent(uint, address, uint);

    function setVars(uint _num) public payable {
        num = _num;
        sender = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value;

        emit ProxyEvent(num, sender, value);
    }
}
```

`Test.js`

```js
describe("MyProxy", function() {
  const value = ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01');
    let proxy;
    let logic;
    before(async () => {
      const Proxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("Proxy");
      proxy = await Proxy.deploy();
      await proxy.deployed();

      const Logic = await ethers.getContractFactory("Logic");
      logic = await Logic.deploy();
      await logic.deployed();
    })

  it("should run delegatecall", async function() {
    
    const tx = await proxy.setVars(logic.address, 15, { value, gasLimit: 100000 });
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(receipt);
    
  });
});
```

`Error`

`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Delegate call failed at Proxy.setVars (contracts/Proxy.sol:13)`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the function signature, you have to use `uint256` instead of `uint`

```
abi.encodeWithSignature("setVars(uint256)", _num)
```